# Core Data relation type question

Tags: objective-c, core-data, object, entity-relationship

Hia,

assumed I have a one to one or one to may relation.
Lets say class Foo has a one to one reference to the managed class Bar.

```
Foo.h
Bar * bar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Bar * bar;
Foo.m
@syntesize bar;
```

I would access Foo this way:

```
Foo * myFoo= [fetched result what ever];
```

Using myFoo.bar.whatEverPoperty is working, but saving myFoo.bar in something like Bar * myBar is not.

Any idea why?

Edit:

```
SomeClass.h
Bar * myBarRef;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Bar * myBarRef;
SomeClass.m
@synthesize myBarRef;
```

now I create an object of that class:

```
SomeClass * mySomeClass= [[SomeClass Alloc]init];
```

and store the reference there:
    mySomeClass.myBarRef= myFoo.bar;    (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

occasional he highlight this line instead of the above:

```
@synthesize myBarRef; (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)
```

---

Could the problem be lazy loading? If yes, how force bar to be load with foo?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do that isn't working. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If, by 'lazy loading' you refer to Core Data faulting mechanism, no, that's transparent for the client. Loading the object is done automatically when accessing the relation.

Comment: Your question can not be answered without more insight in (real) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that you are accessing uninitialized memory; probably a released object.

If the crash occurs in the line `mySomeClass.myBarRef = myFoo.bar;` either `mySomeClass` or `myFoo` is uninitialized or released.

You should re-read the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

If you still cannot find the bug, use the debugger. It'll tell you in which method exactly the bad access happens.

You can (and always should) also [switch on zombie support](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECZOMBIES) (set the environment variable `NSZombieEnabled` to `YES`.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you. However, I verified the existence of every object. mySomeClass is there and so is myFoo. I can set and get every property of mySomeClass, increase its retain count, but I cant store myFoo.bar there. I can create Bar * localBar and store it there, have access to every of its properties and can manually increase the retain count as well. Like I said, the objects are there.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`? You can do this in XCode from: Run -> Manage Breakpoints -> Stop on Objective-C exceptions. When you run your app in the debugger with that option enabled, you will be able to accurately pinpoint the line of code that causes the crash.

Comment: Tried with all errors before. Doesnt fire. Just tried with just Obj. C. Same (asa expected) <br> What is in myFoo.bar stored? An Object address or something else?

Comment: I have other references in my Foo Class. Those work just fine, but not this.

Comment: No bug with core data or the worker class ivars, but with an int array with 6 ints filled with 100 ints. So in a very indirect way, your answer was right.